# Send intent to BroadcastReceiver with pendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I want to send a object (birthday) using AlarmManager to broadcastRecieve to notify ( reminder)

```
alarmManager= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent=new Intent(NewBirthdayActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

            intent.putExtra("birthday",birthDay);
           // sendBroadcast(intent);
            pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NewBirthdayActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and in broadcastRecieve

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //c thong tin se duoc tiep nhan o day
    //no co the chay ngam
    Log.d("TAGGGGGGGGGG:","da nhan duoc thong tin dang ky");
    BirthDay birthDay= (BirthDay) intent.getSerializableExtra(  "birthday");


    if(birthDay!=null){
        String title=birthDay.getName();
        String content=birthDay.getNote();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notify)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(content);
        //co the set them conten cho notify o day
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

but the birthday always null, I can't get data from birthday to set notify.
Pless help me resolve it . 
UPDATE: I was convert object Birthay to byte array and send it. it work!

Comment: While I discuss custom `Parcelable` objects in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html), the same problem occurs with `Serializable`. I try not to use custom types with `Intent` extras as a result, particularly in a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: hi, sory, I'm understand. I mean if I using " sendBroadcast(intent);" it work, but with pending inten for alarmservice it get null

Comment: Correct. Using custom `Parcelable` and `Serializable` classes in extras of a `PendingIntent` can cause problems like this. I recommend not doing that.

Comment: oh, so how I can set time to notify if I don't using it. huhu

Comment: Rather than putting the time and note in a `BirthDay`, save them in two separate extras. Or, save the primary key to your database table in the extra, and load the data from the database when needed.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer. This will remove the question from the list of open questions and maybe help others with the same problem.

Comment: I have updated the solution in the question section. So anyone can make same to resolve